# How to create multi hops SSH tunnel using PuTTY?

Tags: ssh, proxy, putty, tunnel

I have 5 VPS , I use jump command in OpenSSH to connect from My_Pc to VPS_5 .

My_PC ==>VPS_1 ==>VPS_2 ==>VPS_3 ==>VPS_4 ==>VPS_5 ==>Internet

```
ssh -D80 root@VPS_5 -J root@VPS_1,root@VPS_2,root@VPS_3,root@VPS_4
```

In first my PC connect to VPS_1 then VPS_1 connect to VPS_2 , ... I copy Public key and no need enter password in any VPS . In end I use 127.0.0.1:80 for proxy .

---

How can I implement the above example in PuTTY?

Please explain clearly and completely, I am a newbie. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by configuring a ["local proxy command"](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-proxy).

---

For one hop (an equivalent of `root@VPS_2 -J root@VPS_1`), you can use a local proxy command like:

```
plink root@VPS_1
```

Though this can be achieved more easily using *"SSH to proxy and use port forwarding"*.

---

For two hop (an equivalent of `root@VPS_3 -J root@VPS_1,root@VPS_2`) you can use proxy command like:

```
plink root@VPS_2 -proxycmd "plink root@VPS_1"
```

[image]

---

Not sure what is right syntax for three hops, as it need nested quotes and I do not know the syntax for their escaping, if it is possible at all.

But in any case, you can achieve it by configuring stored site in PuTTY  (`hop_1_and_2`) for the additional hosts and then invoking them in the `plink` command:

```
plink root@VPS_3 -proxycmd "plink hop_1_and_2"
```

---

In all cases, you might need to cache host keys of individual hops, before `plink` will be able to automatically connect.